# How to use CLR DLL library in IronScheme

Tags: ironscheme

I have just get started in IronScheme , and I really want to know how to add another CLR DLL library in IronScheme. Since many other Iron Stuff have `AddReference` function to get this down to work instantly , I can't find it in IronScheme. The closest one I can reach is `clr-reference`. But this seem not very useful .
This is my sample on F#: http://pastebin.com/wDQnjMyq

If you can, please help me "translate this" to IronScheme. Thank .

Answer (score 2):

You will find the fixes for this in IronScheme 1.0 RC 2 onwards.

PS: 1.0 RC 3 is coming out today :)